# How to delete a selected row in jsp?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, web

I have created a table in the jsp, for the table the data will be loaded from database and rendered into the jsp or web page to show the all appointments , in this particular scenario i want to delete the selected row from database .

The tried code is below but couldn't make it happen and no error is shown as well:

JSP:

```
 <main>
                <h1 style="margin-left:5rem; text-align: center; margin-top:4%;"> Scheduled Appointments </h1>
                <div class="title-box">
                <form method="POST">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="{empty list}">
                            <h1>No upcoming Appointments</h1>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <table class="styled-table" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top:15px;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Patient Name</th>  
                                        <th>Appointment Date</th>
                                        <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <c:forEach items="${list}" var="record">
                                  <c:if test="${record.ageInDays lt 1}">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="active-row">
                                            <td>${record.name}</td>
                                            <td>${record.date}</td>
                                            <td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Appointment/delete"><input type="" name="id" value="${record.appointmentId}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody> 
                                  </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </table >
                        </form>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                </div>
            </main>
```

Servlet:

```
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       if(request.getServletPath().contains("/delete")){
        /* deleting the appointment*/
        int id= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        if(id>0){
        StaffManager.getInstance().deleteAppointments(id);
    
         List list = new ArrayList<>();//Creating a list to hold data
         list = StaffManager.getInstance().getAppointments();//MVC method implementation for Searching patient 
         request.setAttribute("list", list);
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/Appointments.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
       }
      
    }
```

The staff Manager:

```
 public void deleteAppointments(int id) {
       staff.deleteAppointments(id);
    }
```

The Dao Class:

```
public void deleteAppointments(int id) {
    
    try{
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms", "root", "");
 PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM appointments WHERE  AppointmentsID = ? ");
 st.setInt(1, id);
 st.executeUpdate();
}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    
}
}
```

I'm still new into java web development , so please excuse for not always following the best practices here .
And would really appreciate help to make this work , thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to use a debugger and you will be able to check if you are getting the id to the backend and so on. You can check each step to see where it's going wrong. Or you can place some System.out.println in each method to see if you are getting there and also print some variables.

Comment: what is `staff.deleteAppointments(id);? `are you entering the method where it deletes from the database?

Comment: Hi, you  can pass your id as well in your href i.e :`"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Appointment/delete?id=${record.appointmentId}"` then whenever your `a` tag is clicked id value will also get pass to your server . But, as  you are calling server page via `a` tag it will be `GET` request not `POST` .

Comment: Yes well thank you so much for pointing @Swati , it did work thanks a lot